# Add/update post meta after new/edited custom post type post

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In **WordPress 4.7** I am attempting to **add/update post meta** when an admin **creates or makes a change** to a **WooCommerce product** in the dashboard.

I am doing this using a function on the action `save_post_post_type` as show to be used from WP3.7+ at: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/

Here is my function:

```
    function my_function() {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_gravity_form_data', 'a:15:{s:2:"id";s:1:"3";s:13:"display_title";b:0;s:19:"display_description";b:0;s:25:"disable_woocommerce_price";s:2:"no";s:12:"price_before";s:0:"";s:11:"price_after";s:0:"";s:20:"disable_calculations";s:2:"no";s:22:"disable_label_subtotal";s:2:"no";s:21:"disable_label_options";s:2:"no";s:19:"disable_label_total";s:2:"no";s:14:"disable_anchor";s:2:"no";s:14:"label_subtotal";s:8:"Subtotal";s:13:"label_options";s:7:"Options";s:11:"label_total";s:5:"Total";s:8:"use_ajax";s:2:"no";}');
    }
    add_action( 'save_post_product', 'my_function', 10 );
```

The custom post type (set by WooCommerce) is **product**

I cannot seem to get this to fire. I did manage to do at some point which fired when creating (not editing) a product but I have since amended the code too many times to retrace.

I have tried with transients, add_post_meta, wp_insert_post, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using `wp_insert_post` (works on new/edits) and checking for the post type in a conditional.

A side issue was that I was attempting to add in serialized data and `update_post_meta` serializes the data.